# Redirect www to non-www if subdomain

Tags: redirect, subdomain

My domain http://vietnam.asiastreetfood.com works fine. But if somebody calls http://www.vietnam.asiastreetfood.com theres an error. I cannot enter www.vietnam as a subdomain at 1und1.de. So any ideas how i can redirect the www to the non-www domain?

This is what i tried:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.vietnam.asiastreetfood\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://vietnam.asiastreetfood.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that 'www' is technically a subdomain itself or at least a prefix not generally used with a "sub-domain", so in order to get www.sub.domain.com you have to configure a vhost on the server (much more complicated than an htaccess). Here is a [Media Temple article](https://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/1080/Use+www+prefix+with+subdomain#dv_managed) I found as a starting point.

But this won't be possible on 1und1.de - you will have to contact their support and see if they can configure this (unlikely).